# Request blocking/waiting when reload

Tags: performance, browser, request, blocking

I have an application deployed on production. And users are complaining of it being slow.
What i noticed seems to be a bit strange with me.

In case I open an URL normally(entering it in url bar and hitting enter). It every request seems to be loaded normally.
But if I do a reload(pressing Ctrl+R) many of the requests seems to be blocked for some time until they are sent to the server and processed.
Obviously it makes my app slow. Differences in time sometime reach to even 4-5 sec between the two cases.

Tech Stack:

- Python 3.8 (Flask)
- Gunicorn
- Nginx

I have tried in multiple browsers multiple times. Same issue for all of them.
Tried searching on the internet says it has something to do with number of simultaneous requests we can make to a single server. But still couldn't figure out when it is happening only with reload.

**Opening url normally (takes 3-6 sec)**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**With Reload (takes more than 7sec)**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Below is the detailed illustration about one of the blocked request on Firefox.
[image]